# Controller method not found when button inside template is pressed

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a project using NodeJS, Express and AngularJS that will have a search form (added via custom directive) and a search results that must be loaded only after the search button is pressed.

The problem is that the method I have created inside the controller can't be found from the search form. 
Here is a sample of my code:

app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['app-directives']);

  app.controller('AppController', function() {
    this.buttonClick = function() {
      alert('Test');
    };
  });
})();
```

directives.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('app-directives', []);

    app.directive('searchForm', function() {
       return {
         retrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: '/partials/search-form.html'
       };
    });

    app.directive('searchResults', function() {
       return {
         retrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: '/partials/search-results.html'
       };
    });
})();
```

search-form.html

```
<input type="text" id="query" />
<button onclick="buttonClick">Search</button>
```

page-content.html

```
<section id="mainContent">
    <search-form></search-form>
    <search-results></search-results>
</section>
```

---

UPDATE

The second question will be posted in another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first question:

You are using onclick attribute instead angular's 'ng-click' in the button search. This could be the problem. And do not forget to also add the 'ng-app' and 'ng-controller' tags. If not, your method will never be visible.

I also would recommend you to use $scope service instead of 'this' for attaching models and functions you later will use in your views.

Regards